# Paypal Express Checkout Curl Failing on Live, but working in Sandbox

Tags: php, curl, paypal, express-checkout

I'm stumped, because this was working, but now, all of a sudden, it does not work.

I use Paypal's Express Checkout and have the following code:

```
$post = array(
        'USER'=>$username,
        'PWD'=>$password,
        'SIGNATURE'=>$signature,
        'METHOD'=>'SetExpressCheckout',
        'VERSION'=>'119',
        [... All the other info  to be sent to Paypal...]
        );
$post = http_build_query($post);

$live_curl = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
$sandbox_curl = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $live_curl);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3); // 3 seconds to connect
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); // 10 seconds to complete
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

When I use the sandbox url it works fine, but on the live server I get this error:

> cUrl error (#28): Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received

This has worked for a long time, I even received an order through it recently, but it doesn't work now!

**Edit:** My website has SSL, so setting `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` like we see in so many answers to questions like this, is not an option.  That defeats the purpose of a secure checkout.  Besides, I've tried it in all my debugging, and does not work.

**Update:** I set `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` to `TRUE` and got this:

> Hostname was found in DNS cache
>   Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped
>   Trying 173.0.84.69...
>   Connected to api-3t.paypal.com (173.0.84.69) port 443 (#0)
>   successfully set certificate verify locations:
>   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
>   CApath: none
>   Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
>   Closing connection 0

Comment: Try adding the following `CURLOPT` options : `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);` - PayPal have been rolling out some security upgrades but there's nothing that should have *just* gone live https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1913&expand=true&locale=en_US

Comment: First off: That didn't work.  Second: That defeats the purpose of having a secure checkout.  Plus `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` already defaults to `2`. See https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST.html

Comment: Kind of... the encryption is still in place but the CA chain isn't being verified - there was an issue with a certain version of cURL that I ran into where it failed to connect to PayPal (or anything over HTTPS) when host verification was set to `true` but that was a while ago though, figured it was worth a shot as a test, but it does leave you open to MITM attacks... you are doing pretty much the same thing that I am though from what I can tell.

Comment: Only difference I can see is that I'm using longer timeouts and setting `CURLOPT_INTERFACE` to `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` (since I'm running several sites through a single installed codebase)

Comment: Well, that's the thing. This was just working a couple days ago.  I haven't changed anything!  Could it possibly be an issue on Paypal's end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted my host and asked them if anything had been changed recently that may have affected this.  They said:

> I think I know what caused this. We set the MTU to 1476 company wide
>   to fix some issues. I changed it back to 1500.

Well, that didn't work. So he changed it to 1400 and all of a sudden it works!

So the logical question for me was

> Why would diminishing the MTU make it work?

Their answer:

> This is due to the new DDOS protection. I would like to escalate this ticket and have it investigated further so we can narrow down why the reduction to 1476 did not resolve this issue for you.

So the escalated support agent says:

> 1476 should work just fine and I've tried to connect to the
>   https://api-3t.paypal.com site from a system with MTU set to 1476 and
>   it worked just fine for me.

Well, yes.  It actually always worked for me from the command line.

So he changed my site's MTU back to 1476 and surprise!
It works just fine.

So, what was the real problem in the end?  I don't know.
As far as I know all settings are back to what they were when it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem , and was hitting my head against the desk, and then read this post, so i contacted my hosting provider and this was their answer

> Thank you for contacting our Technical Support Department.
>
> We have recently changed our DDoS protection provider and have
>   encountered such issues with curl queries.
>
> You should not receive the error anymore.
>
> Please verify.

And the paypal gateway started to work again. So contact your hosting provider first.